# OpenCL - kernel running slow

Tags: select, kernel, opencl

My kernel is pretty simple. It tries to see if the codes are valid and then stores only the unique codes according to the prefix scan output:

```
__kernel void moveValid(__global int* sortCode, __global int* mark, __global int* processorOffsets, __global int* uniqueCode,__global int* numPoints, __global int* pointIndex) 
{
    int ig = get_global_id(0);
    int m = mark[ig];
    int j= processorOffsets[ig];
    atomic_inc(&numPoints[j-1]);
    // select
    if(m == true)
    {   
            uniqueCode[j] = sortCode[ig];
            pointIndex[j] = ig;
    }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

Seems like the kernel is really slow. Is it due to the if statement? Can anyone give any tips as to how the kernel can be improved? Also can select be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, without looking too deeply at your code, I can give the following feedback about its speed.  I am assuming that you are using a GPU as your device.  If you are using a CPU as your device, some on the information may still apply.

> atomic_inc(&numPoints[j-1]);

Atomic increments are PAINFULLY slow to global memory on most devices.  This is because that data has to be committed into global memory (can't be cached locally).

> barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

This barrier insures that all work_items in the work_group are present before continuing execution.  Why do you need this in your code?  Especially when nothing is left to do, there is no reason to not allow your threads to finish execution.  This is also a big performance hit.

> if(m == true)

This is not actually the worst if statement I've seen, because it only has one branch.  This will still slow down your code, but not as substantially as other things.  The condition will be computed for all threads in serial (for some architectures) before continuing.

Overall, in this code you are performing 4 global memory access as on atomic operation and no math operations.  GPUs are the worst type of device to do this type of algorithm because memory accesses are exceptionally slow to global memory especially if the accesses are coalesced.  Could you consider moving some of your arrays to local memory instead?

Comment: Thank you. I am still not quite sure of where to put the barrier in a kernel and when. I have changed the atomic_inc to local memory. The kernel is running faster.

Comment: Normally you will not need a barrier.  Barriers will only be needed when you are doing work then want to wait for your work_group and then do more work.  Also, it's likely that the barrier doesn't work the way that you think it does.  If you want a global barrier (e.g. The same amount of work done by each work-group) then do it through kernel executions instead of using barrier.  Also make sure you understand the differences between the different memories (global, local, private) instead of just using them.